# Is there an R package to clean and separate seabird trips in R?

Tags: gps, data-cleaning, telemetry

I am working with telemetry data (lon, lat, date and time) of several individual boobies. To analyze the data I have to find outliers in the coordinates, the most obvious ones are easy to clean but the less obvious ones are not. It is also necessary to cut the trips, because for each individual there can be more than one trip (trip = each time it leaves and returns to the colony) and if possible there should be only one point that refers to the colony. Finally it is necessary to identify/separate the trips that are complete from the incomplete ones.
Is there a package to do thia now?

Data separated by individuals and trips, without outliers in lon and lat and where you can identify if the trip was completed or not.